# HTML - Скрыть текст и код

Tags: html

Вопрос глупый, но ответа я найти не смог. (Либо я плохо искал...) Вот у меня есть сайт, там две ссылки, одна скрытая при помощи display:none но код ссылки остается открытый, и её можно просмотреть, возможно ли как то скрыть её код?
+ Кратко говоря, нужно сделать что бы HTML код элемента не был виден при его просмотре в браузере. Как это реализовать?

Comment: о каком "коде ссылки" идет речь?

Comment: Обычная ссылка: `<a href=""></a>`...

Comment: Можете показать пример, что есть и как должно быть, либо набросок сделать?

Comment: странно, у меня нету никакого кода, ссылка скрыта и все

Comment: Кратко говоря мне требуется скрыть код элемента. Надеюсь так более ясно?

Comment: О чём здесь идёт речь, если элемента не должно быть не только на странице, но и в коде? Просто забудьте про него и все дела.

Comment: Суть в том, что автор имел ввиду, что у него есть 2 ссылки, одна должна не просто скрываться от  пользователя визуально, но и исчезать из кода.
display:none скрывает элемент визуально, но не врезает ее из кода. Как уже дан ответ, то полностью вырезать можно только при помощи js-кода, либо через back-end, например, при помощи PHP. HTML и CSS не дают возможностей для "вырезания" кусков кода подобным образом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь, наверное, только два варианта:

1. Если html код страницы генерирует backend, тогда не выводить ссылку
   на стороне backend;
2. Удалять ссылку через js. Но при таком подходе, если на клиенте отключен js, ссылка останется в коде.

```js
document.getElementById("link_id_hidden").remove();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Учу bootstrap</title>
</head>

<body>

  <a href="#" id='link_id_hidden'>hidden link</a>
  <a href="#" id='link_id'>link</a>
</body>

</html>
```